# How to update custom user fields on Drupal 8

Tags: php, oop, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I try to update/save a custom Field of User Profile on Drupal 8.
I am lucky to get Values but not to save them back.

Here is my Code, any1 knows why this won’t work?
I've tried different variations of these already.

```
 $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);  // Load USER of ID=1
 $user->set(‚field_user_curpage‘,38); //set my custom field = 38 !!!
 $user->save();  // save …
```

This is how I Load these fields:

```
    $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);  // Load user with id = 1
    $curpage_load = $user->get(‚field_user_curpage‘); // Load custom field from User Profile
    $curpage = preg_replace(‚/[^0-9]/‚, ‚‘, $curpage_load->value);  // filter for No. only
    return $curpage;  // return output this
```

Comment: perhaps something like that:

`$edit = $user->set('field_user_curpage', 38);
$user->save($user, $edit);`

but doesn’t work either :(

Answer (score 2):

The [Entity Load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3Aload/8.2.x) function returns a static object.

Try loading the user with this instead.
`\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user')->load($id);`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The Load works fine but the set/save doesn’t.
i changed the load user Line to yours but i still won’t be able to change/save back the Field.

Comment: I have used "load", "set", "save" many times and it has always worked for me. These are standard content entity functions, so it should work.

Comment: Maybe explain why your think it isn't working. I know on a recent job I did I also had to set something else so a new revision would display in the content revisions list, though I am not sure if this applies to you.